# Producer Consumer should I use a mutex or a semaphore

Tags: c, producer-consumer

I have 2 threads, the `producer` thread receives some data over an internet socket, constructs an object and adds it to a queue and the `consumer` thread pops items from that same queue and does some processing.

Since both threads modify the queue (by enqueuing and dequeuing respectively) I think using a mutex  in both threads should be sufficient. Is this a good approach or should I use a semaphore? If so, why?

Comment: There is a lot of room for opinion here.  Examples exist that support either approach for protecting a resource such as you have described.   If you could add some additional detail on your specific design, it may start to indicate one method over the other.  As described here, either method will work.

Comment: Try to read up on differences between a mutex and semaphore, and analyze where one fits to get the required functionality. You might even find that you need to use both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either can be made to work.  It depends on details of the actual design.  How many producer/consumer requests will you allow simultaneously?  Is it truly limited to two threads, or will the code spawn others as more requests occur?

I found this short [blog](https://afteracademy.com/blog/difference-between-mutex-and-semaphore-in-operating-system) interesting.  It discusses and compares both the `Mutex` and `Semaphore` and may give you some ideas.

> *"A `mutex` object allows multiple process threads to access a single shared resource but only one at a time. On the other hand, semaphore
> allows multiple process threads to access the finite instance of the
> resource until available. In mutex, the lock can be acquired and
> released by the same process at a time."*

Examples in C

- [One queue accessed by multiple threads using mutex](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sharing-queue-among-three-threads/)
- [Blocking Queue in C++ using semaphores](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247483/blocking-queue-in-c-using-semaphores)  (Not C specific, but concept will be same.)